# i2c registering macro not found?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, i2c

I ame working on I2C driver on a raspPi:

```
/* register I2C device static */
static const struct i2c_board_info rasp_i2c_devices[] = {
    { "mbed", mbedID },
};

/* in the init function of my module */
i2c_register_board_info(0,rasp_i2c_devices,ARRAY_SIZE(rasp_i2c_devices));
```

When i compile i get following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zilleplus/rasp/linux'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "i2c_register_board_info" [/home/zilleplus/LedCube/Module/I2C/I2Crasp.ko] undefined!
```

--> cross compiled kernel with make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${PITOOLSBIN} CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y

Where do i go to from here? i did include `#include <linux/i2c.h>`
i dont realy understand why i get this error.

pastebin with small module demonstrating problem:
http://pastebin.com/ch58BUZj

---

in response to comment piece of my .config:

```
CONFIG_I2C=y
CONFIG_I2C_BOARDINFO=y
CONFIG_I2C_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_I2C_CHARDEV=y
CONFIG_I2C_HELPER_AUTO=y
CONFIG_I2C_ALGOBIT=m
```

Comment: Did you enable "CONFIG_I2C_BOARDINFO" config?

Comment: yes i did forgot to mention that sorry, still same thing weird enough

Comment: Does your system.map has i2c_register_board_info symbol?. Are you compiling against right kernel i.e KSRC path?.

Comment: i compile against right kernel, compiled hello world and a simple char module before this.
The System.map contains this:
c058ed5c T i2c_register_board_info

Comment: Clearly the ko being built is against an old kernel which does NOT have the `i2c_register_board_info`. This most likely points to a problem with your build-command/makefile for the ko.

Comment: Hi @zilleplus, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: not really, its a while ago not sure what i did.